# Localize main menu in C#

Tags: c#, localization

Good night,

Today I learned about localization in C# and now I need to fully localize my application's main menu. The question is whether there is any way to localize it automatically? Currently, I set at design time each `MenuItem`'s `Text`property to be a given string in the resource file and use recursion on `MenuItems`, but this doesn't sound elegant at all... Is there any better way?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Microsoft-supplied detailed walkthrough on how to accomplish this task:

[Walkthrough: Localizing Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use satellite assemblies to contain your local resources